# How would I go about parsing log data in kibana from data that is already indexed?

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

So I work for a startup and we are using Aptible to host our elastic stack.  I'm not sure if that affects anything but figured I'd mention it. I'm the only guy here with any working knowledge of the elastic stack, and it's not very much. So bear with me, please.

Basically the log data from a postgres db and react app gets sent to the elastic stack. When I go to search through it in kibana, I get results that look like this:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2022.03.23",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "yboRtX8B3AbBxU682eag",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2022-03-23T04:38:04.706Z",
    "source": "app",
    "layer": "app",
    "container":xxxxxxxxx
    "app": "our-app",
    "host": xxxxxxx,
    "app_id": xxxxxxx,
    "log": "172.17.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2022:23:37:56 -0500] \"GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.0\" 400 26 \"-\" \"Aptible Health Check\"\n",
    "service": "xxxxxxx",
    "type": "json",
    "@version": "3",
    "file": "/tmp/dockerlogs/f76cd328d5710e817702c5b7c15d37797828a1308f8b0e17d039a86813237f73/f76cd328d5710e817702c5b7c15d37797828a1308f8b0e17d039a86813237f73-json.log",
    "offset": 46118576,
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2022-03-23T04:37:56.192544365Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-03-23T04:38:04.706Z"
    ],
    "time": [
      "2022-03-23T04:37:56.192Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1648010284706
  ]
}
```

This isn't super helpful, since the data I find useful is all in the "log" section.
So here is the log section from above :
`"172.17.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2022:23:37:56 -0500] \"GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.0\" 400 26 \"-\" \"Aptible Health Check\"\n"`

I'd like to parse that, or better yet have kibana or whatever automatically parse that.
I hate to admit I've spent DAYS on this problem, and I just can't figure out how to either have this parsed automatically when it first parses the data coming in, or how to have it done afterward; like take the log data from this JSON and parse it so it ends up as its own JSON.

So any advice here on how to parse that would be great.

Comment: You need to understand the path that data takes to get to Elasticsearch. Your example appears to come from a Docker container's standard output. What reads that output? Are you using a log driver to hook directly to Aptible?

Comment: Once you understand that path, you can look at what parsing can be done before the logs are written to Elasticsearch. After they get there, unfortunately, you don't have the option to parse the messages.

Comment: Depending on what your React app is talking to, you might be able to write that output in JSON, and extract the individual components that way. For example, if you're using nginx, then it's a pretty easy configuration change to get it to write JSON logs.

Comment: But I'm afraid that you're going to have to start by reading documentation. Unless there's somebody who has your exact setup and can tell you what to do.

Comment: To change already indexed data you will need to reindex it, which means read from your current index and index the data in a new index, the reindex process will allow you to change the current data and parse this `log` field. What is the source of this log? NGINX? Apache? Are this the only log type you have? The reindex process is not that hard, if you can give more context about your logs, a better answer could be provided.

Comment: I did read documentation, a buttload of it. Turns out there is A LOT of it. I don't want a Ph.D. in this or to make it my new specialty, I'm just trying to solve one problem. I guess I'll just look more into modifying the log data before it gets to Kibana. As for log management in general, any recommendations for handling logs for a Django API, a React web app, or a React native app? If anyone has used some good software or knows some good guides on how to set this up I'd much appreciate it.